# how to create $resource custom config params to read in an interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I want to create an interceptor that only takes action for specific `$resource` calls. I want the `$resource` calls themselves to specify whether they should be intercepted, rather than creating and maintaining a big whitelist or blacklist for the interceptor to refer to.

For example, using `$http` you can do this:

```
$http.get('/things', { interceptMe: true } );
```

Then in an interceptor:

```
app.factory('anInterceptor', function() {
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            if (response.config.interceptMe) {
                // take action...
            }
         }
    };
});
```

However, with `$resource` there is no argument to specify a config object like this. How can I accomplish this with `$resource` instead of `$http`?

Comment: instead of a global interceptor, it looks like specifying the interceptor to use in a resource action will work: $resource(uri, null, { 'get': { method: 'GET', interceptor: anInterceptor } } );

Comment: specifying the interceptor in the $resource() function is pretty ugly though. this means every $resource call needs to be overridden and configured with the interceptor across the entire application.